# Is it possible to create a function independently outside a package(not in body or header), and then call and execute it within the package?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just want to know if it is possible to this and how to execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
  create or replace function get_it return pls_integer is
  begin
    return 1;
  end;

  create or replace package pck1 as
    function pck_get_it return pls_integer;
  end;

  create or replace package body pck1 as
    function pck_get_it return pls_integer as
    begin
      return get_it;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for! Just another quick question on this. If i were to use a parameter in my independent function, would the header and body functions also use the parameter?

Comment: In the call to your independent function, yes. Whether you add the parameter to your package function is entirely up to you - I'd add it to the package function and possibly provide a sensible default value, so users of your package function can omit it if they want to use the default value.